# string bitwise operation in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, security, bit-manipulation

As I knew the sql server bigint has 64bit length, how do I make a bitwise caculte the bigger than 64bit, and I want to know is there a good way to fix this problem .
I want to design a securirty system that use the binanry to store the a user right in database ,and use bitwise operation to caculate user rights. Does this a good way for that ,thanks for your guys help . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to roll your own bitwise operations because [bigint is not supported by the built-in operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).

Comment: sorry ,I haven't realize that it doesn't support . Do u mean that I need to write user functions for that operation supports .

Comment: It should be possible to split one bigint into two int and work from there.